# Installing Euterpea for computer music applications and Haskell

Tags: haskell, dsl, euterpea

I followed the instructions here http://www.euterpea.com for installing Euterpea (a domain-specific language for computer music applications embedded in Haskell), and I received a message that certain packages and things failed to install (see the code below). How can I install the remaining packages?

```
Mo-MacBook-Pro:~ Mo$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
cabal install Euterpea
To revert to previous state run:
cabal update --index-state='2018-06-25T08:34:14Z'
Mo-MacBook-Pro:~ Mo$ cabal install Euterpea
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-         
command-line-argument]
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading heap-1.0.4...
Downloading PortMidi-0.1.6.1...
Configuring PortMidi-0.1.6.1...
Downloading lazysmallcheck-0.6...
Configuring heap-1.0.4...
Downloading semigroups-0.18.5...
Configuring lazysmallcheck-0.6...
Configuring semigroups-0.18.5...
Building heap-1.0.4...
Building PortMidi-0.1.6.1...
Building lazysmallcheck-0.6...
Building semigroups-0.18.5...
Installed semigroups-0.18.5
Downloading stm-2.5.0.0...
Configuring stm-2.5.0.0...
Installed lazysmallcheck-0.6
Downloading HCodecs-0.5.1...
Installed heap-1.0.4
Downloading Stream-0.4.7.2...
Configuring HCodecs-0.5.1...
Configuring Stream-0.4.7.2...
Building stm-2.5.0.0...
Building HCodecs-0.5.1...
Building Stream-0.4.7.2...
Failed to install HCodecs-0.5.1
Build log ( /Users/Mo/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/HCodecs-0.5.1-    
BtnY8oBJJ5FGnsoQaqbvOm.log ):
cabal: Entering directory      
'/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-   
5294/HCodecs-0.5.1'
Configuring HCodecs-0.5.1...
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-     
command-line-argument]
Preprocessing library for HCodecs-0.5.1..
Building library for HCodecs-0.5.1..
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id random-1.1-    
7T1TXpwb46H1j0av1OnVaD
(use -v for more information)
cabal: Leaving directory    
'/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-  
5294/HCodecs-0.5.1'
Failed to install Stream-0.4.7.2
Build log ( /Users/Mo/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/Stream-0.4.7.2-    
ES6rey5IgWg9tsXDghlP7Y.log ):
cabal: Entering directory     
'/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-    
5295/Stream-0.4.7.2'
Warning: Stream.cabal:6:4: Tabs used as indentation at 6:4, 12:4, 13:4,    
14:4,
15:4, 16:4, 17:4
Configuring Stream-0.4.7.2...
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-   
command-line-argument]
Preprocessing library for Stream-0.4.7.2..
Building library for Stream-0.4.7.2..
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id QuickCheck-2.11.3-    
4Q6LQ7mN6Tj8otrLuHN0se
(use -v for more information)
cabal: Leaving directory    
'/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-    
5295/Stream-0.4.7.2'
Installed PortMidi-0.1.6.1
Installed stm-2.5.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Euterpea-2.0.6-LLo28S848YneLemh6QUkK depends on Euterpea-2.0.6 which     
failed to
install.
HCodecs-0.5.1-BtnY8oBJJ5FGnsoQaqbvOm failed during the building phase.          
The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
Stream-0.4.7.2-ES6rey5IgWg9tsXDghlP7Y failed during the building phase.     
The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
arrows-0.4.4.2-GLke2GgDEro6Tzj3MGmTOB depends on arrows-0.4.4.2 which     
failed
to install.
```

It would be great if someone could help. Thanks.

I have included all the code, lest some particular relevant detail was omitted.

---

Edit

I have also tried to install Euterpea via stack. I get this message:

```
Mo-MacBook-Pro:~ Mo$ stack install Euterpea

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were     
encountered:


In the dependencies for Euterpea-2.0.6:
PortMidi must match ==0.1.6.1, but the stack configuration has no   specified version  (latest matching version is 0.1.6.1)
arrows must match >=0.4 && <0.5, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version is 0.4.4.2)
needed since Euterpea is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver     to attempt to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient     when dealing with many complicated constraint
    errors, but results may be unpredictable.

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in     /Users/Mo/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml:

- PortMidi-0.1.6.1
- arrows-0.4.4.2

Plan construction failed.
```

-- 
Edit 2.

As suggested below, I tried `cabal install random-1.1 --force-reinstalls` which generated:

```
 clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-    Wunused-command-line-argument]
 Resolving dependencies...
 Warning: The following packages are likely to be broken by the      reinstalls:
 tf-random-0.5
 QuickCheck-2.11.3
 Continuing even though the plan contains dangerous reinstalls.
 Configuring random-1.1...
 Building random-1.1...
 Installed random-1.1
```

Then

```
 Mo-MacBook-Pro:~ Mo$ cabal install Euterpea
 clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-   Wunused-command-line-argument]
 Resolving dependencies...
 Configuring Stream-0.4.7.2...
 Configuring HCodecs-0.5.1...
 Building HCodecs-0.5.1...
 Building Stream-0.4.7.2...
 Failed to install HCodecs-0.5.1
 Build log ( /Users/lukeburke/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/HCodecs-0.5.1-    BtnY8oBJJ5FGnsoQaqbvOm.log ):
 cabal: Entering directory      '/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-20742/HCodecs-     0.5.1'
 Configuring HCodecs-0.5.1...
 clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-    Wunused-command-line-argument]
 Preprocessing library for HCodecs-0.5.1..
 Building library for HCodecs-0.5.1..
 <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id random-1.1-   7T1TXpwb46H1j0av1OnVaD
     (use -v for more information)
 cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-20742/HCodecs-  0.5.1'
 Failed to install Stream-0.4.7.2
 Build log ( /Users/Mo/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/Stream-0.4.7.2-     ES6rey5IgWg9tsXDghlP7Y.log ):
 cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-20743/Stream-  0.4.7.2'
 Warning: Stream.cabal:6:4: Tabs used as indentation at 6:4, 12:4,    13:4, 14:4,
 15:4, 16:4, 17:4
 Configuring Stream-0.4.7.2...
 clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-  Wunused-command-line-argument]
 Preprocessing library for Stream-0.4.7.2..
 Building library for Stream-0.4.7.2..
 <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id QuickCheck-2.11.3-    4Q6LQ7mN6Tj8otrLuHN0se
(use -v for more information)
 cabal: Leaving directory   '/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-20743/Stream-    0.4.7.2'
 cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
 Euterpea-2.0.6-LLo28S848YneLemh6QUkK depends on Euterpea-2.0.6 which   failed to
 install.
 HCodecs-0.5.1-BtnY8oBJJ5FGnsoQaqbvOm failed during the building phase.     The
 exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
 Stream-0.4.7.2-ES6rey5IgWg9tsXDghlP7Y failed during the building   phase. The
 exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
 arrows-0.4.4.2-GLke2GgDEro6Tzj3MGmTOB depends on arrows-0.4.4.2 which   failed
 to install.
```

---

Edit 3

It has been suggested below that multiple packages are botched and that I should try re-installing all of them (in a single command, i.e. `cabal install random tf-random QuickCheck Euterpea --force-reinstalls`.

However, if I write `cabal install random tf-random QuickCheck Euterpea --force-reinstalls` I receive the following code:

```
 clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-   Wunused-command-line-argument]
 Resolving dependencies...
 Warning: The following packages are likely to be broken by the   reinstalls:
 QuickCheck-2.11.3
 Continuing even though the plan contains dangerous reinstalls.
 Downloading erf-2.0.0.0...
 Configuring random-1.1...
 Configuring erf-2.0.0.0...
 Building random-1.1...
 Building erf-2.0.0.0...
 Installed erf-2.0.0.0
 Installed random-1.1
 Downloading tf-random-0.5...
 Configuring tf-random-0.5...
 Building tf-random-0.5...
 Failed to install tf-random-0.5
Build log ( /Users/Mo/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.4.3/tf-random-0.5-  ADZoyzEXgHe6hyR0Bycce0.log ):
 cabal: Entering directory      '/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-21584/tf-   random-0.5'
 Configuring tf-random-0.5...
 clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-   Wunused-command-line-argument]
 Preprocessing library for tf-random-0.5..
Building library for tf-random-0.5..
 <command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id primitive-0.6.4.0-  9k41Y6ToOAE8KXK6VMGV2O
     (use -v for more information)
 cabal: Leaving directory   '/var/folders/dy/q51p3v595kbd8_wclmt80v700000gn/T/cabal-tmp-21584/tf-   random-0.5'
 cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
 Euterpea-2.0.6-87WYqltNL8w8teqXOsc4TL depends on Euterpea-2.0.6 which    failed
 to install.
 HCodecs-0.5.1-DrGKEnNk6EBHti2goL6KP5 depends on HCodecs-0.5.1 which.  failed to
 install.
 QuickCheck-2.12.6.1-KuXpgimNOXzF2SmGPEs5LR depends on QuickCheck-  2.12.6.1
 which failed to install.
 Stream-0.4.7.2-FedzVSwUnWMDxlzmPNWt7x depends on Stream-0.4.7.2 which   failed
 to install.
 arrows-0.4.4.2-EGvZPpby4BcD99TcXDoCg4 depends on arrows-0.4.4.2 which.  failed
 to install.
 tf-random-0.5-ADZoyzEXgHe6hyR0Bycce0 failed during the building phase.   The
 exception was:
 ExitFailure 1
```

What can I do to install Euterpea?

Comment: Looks like HCodecs is the first missing link. My next step would be to try to install it manually (go get the source).

Comment: Oh it can't find random-1.1, but didn't try to install it. Use -v as it suggests. I might also try unregistering random-1.1 with ghc-pkg and going and pruning it from the cabal dir.  The package db could be corrupted (sadly it does happen from time to time)

Comment: How do I unregister random-1.1 with ghc-pkg and prune it from the cabal dir? So I that first and then try `cabal install Euterpea`?

Comment: I would try `cabal install random-1.1 --reinstall`. (Might be necessary to also add `--force-reinstalls`.)

Comment: I wrote `--force-reinstalls` and it says `-bash: --force-reinstalls: command not found`

Comment: I think the answer might be here https://github.com/Euterpea/Euterpea2/issues/21 , however I do not understand the procedure described on that page ("I just pushed a small change to the repository (it needed a newer version of HCodecs). Please try it using the version on GitHub and let me know what happens.. Once cloned with git (or downloaded & unzipped), cd into the Euterpea2 directory and run just "cabal install" without anything else after it to install from the local copy.")

Comment: I have also edited my question.

Comment: If you want to reply to commenters, you should ping them with e.g. `@leftaroundabout`. — Your issue doesn't seem related to the one on Github you linked to. And the Stack issue isn't related to the one you had with Cabal-install. Please keep the question focused on one topic.

Comment: @leftaroundabout are you able to help?

Comment: I _may_ be able to help with the problems in Cabal, but you need to say what happened with the attempted reinstall.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have edited the question, saying what happened with the attempted reinstall. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Apparently multiple packages are botched. Have you tried re-installing all of them (in a single command, i.e. `cabal install random tf-random QuickCheck Euterpea --force-reinstalls`)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I have tried `cabal install random tf-random QuickCheck Euterpea --force-reinstalls` and written the code that resulted under Edit 3 in the re-edited question. It didn't work. However, maybe I didn't understand you. Do I need to enter a similar command which includes all the failed installs? How would I do this?

Comment: I'm starting to think your entire package DB is broken. Might be worth nuking the complete `~/.cabal` and `~/.ghc` folders so _all_ packages will be installed from scratch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Installing the Euterpea package**

This answer uses LTS 12.26 as I've verified it works, but this should work for most LTS releases (see bottom of step 2 for details).

1. Make a new Stack project:

   ```
   stack new euter-test
   cd euter-test
   ```
2. Edit `stack.yaml` and set the LTS to 12.26 and `extra-deps` to specify the versions of packages that aren't present in the LTS but are present on Hackage:

   ```
   resolver: lts-12.26
   ...
   extra-deps:
   - Euterpea-2.0.6
   - PortMidi-0.1.6.1
   - arrows-0.4.4.2
   - Stream-0.4.7.2
   - lazysmallcheck-0.6
   ```

   The errors you were getting on the Stack install ("PortMidi must match ==0.1.6.1, but the stack configuration has no specified version") indicate that a package you're using requires a particular version of a library, but the package repository (LTS snapshot) doesn't contain that library, so you need to specify it explicitly. Stack then prints which library and version is missing, so you can just keep trying `stack build` and adding the libraries until the build succeeds.

   We use LTS 12.26 here, but by adding the `extra-deps` packages as described above, you should be able to get it working on any LTS.
3. Edit `package.yaml` and add `Euterpea` to the list of dependencies:

   ```
   dependencies:
   ...
   - Euterpea
   ```
4. A simple test in `app/Main.hs`:

   ```
   module Main where

   import Euterpea

   main :: IO ()
   main = play $ c 4 qn
   ```
5. Run `stack build`:

   ```
   lazysmallcheck-0.6: download
   heap-1.0.4: download       
   heap-1.0.4: configure      
   HCodecs-0.5.1: download    
   PortMidi-0.1.6.1: download 
   heap-1.0.4: build          
   lazysmallcheck-0.6: configure
   lazysmallcheck-0.6: build  
   HCodecs-0.5.1: configure   
   HCodecs-0.5.1: build       
   PortMidi-0.1.6.1: configure
   heap-1.0.4: copy/register  
   lazysmallcheck-0.6: copy/register
   PortMidi-0.1.6.1: build                                          
   Stream-0.4.7.2: download                                     
   Stream-0.4.7.2: configure                                    
   Stream-0.4.7.2: build                                        
   Stream-0.4.7.2: copy/register                                
   PortMidi-0.1.6.1: copy/register                              
   arrows-0.4.4.2: download                                     
   arrows-0.4.4.2: configure                  
   arrows-0.4.4.2: build                      
   arrows-0.4.4.2: copy/register              
   HCodecs-0.5.1: copy/register               
   Euterpea-2.0.6: download    
   Euterpea-2.0.6: configure   
   Euterpea-2.0.6: build       
   Euterpea-2.0.6: copy/register
   Building all executables for `euter' once. After a successful build of all of them, only specified executables will be rebuilt.
   euter-0.1.0.0: configure (lib + exe)
   Configuring euter-0.1.0.0...
   euter-0.1.0.0: build (lib + exe)
   Preprocessing library for euter-0.1.0.0..
   Building library for euter-0.1.0.0..
   [1 of 2] Compiling Lib              ( src/Lib.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Lib.o )
   [2 of 2] Compiling Paths_euter      ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/autogen/Paths_euter.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/Paths_euter.o )
   Preprocessing executable 'euter-exe' for euter-0.1.0.0..
   Building executable 'euter-exe' for euter-0.1.0.0..
   [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( app/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/euter-exe/euter-exe-tmp/Main.o )
   [2 of 2] Compiling Paths_euter      ( .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/euter-exe/autogen/Paths_euter.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/euter-exe/euter-exe-tmp/Paths_euter.o )
   Linking .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-2.2.0.1/build/euter-exe/euter-exe ...

   euter-0.1.0.0: copy/register
   Installing library in <...>
   Installing executable euter-exe in <...>
   Registering library for euter-0.1.0.0..
   ```
6. Running the executable produced by the project should emit a tone if you're running a MIDI synthesiser:

   ```
   stack exec euter-test-exe
   ```

---

**Troubleshooting**

- If you get an error like `*** Exception: No MIDI outputs!`, then you're not running a MIDI synthesiser (see below). Make sure you run it in the background (eg. in another terminal).
- If you don't get an error but there's no audio output, try running `devices` in GHCI to see what outputs are available, and then use `playDev x` instead of `play`, where `x` is the OutputDeviceID of the synth input port. Eg:

  ```
  > devices
  Input devices:
    InputDeviceID 1   Midi Through Port-0
  Output devices:
    OutputDeviceID 0  Midi Through Port-0
    OutputDeviceID 2  Synth input port (25952:0)
  > playDev 2 $ c 4 qn
  ```
- If you run `devices` and don't see any synth input ports, but you have fluidsynth running in the background, then you might need to restart `ghci` and try again.

---

**Running a MIDI synthesiser**

Here's a quick step-by-step to get Fluidsynth running on Debian (with guesses at a Mac setup along the way).

1. Install fluidsynth:
   On Debian this is `sudo apt install fluidsynth`, on mac it could be `brew install fluidsynth` - there's quite a few articles on how to do this, just google it if in doubt.
2. Run fluidsynth:
   On Debian using ALSA this is

   ```
   fluidsynth -s -a alsa -m alsa_seq /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2
   ```

   Instructing fluidsynth to run in server mode, use `alsa` as the audio driver and `alsa_seq` as the MIDI driver, and use the soundfont `FluidR3_GM.sf2` (should be installed as part of the fluidsynth install).

   On Mac, it seems like the correct commandline is:

   ```
   fluidsynth -s -a coreaudio -m coremidi /usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2
   ```

   If you can't find the `FluidR3_GM.sf2` file then it's likely it's been installed in a different location. As a last resort, you can just download a soundfont file and use that rather than the one provided by FluidSynth.

   After running this, you should be given a prompt and maybe a few warnings, and fluidsynth will be running. Make sure it's running before using Euterpea, and keep it running while using Euterpea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186294/discussion-between-hnefatl-and-user65526).

Comment: @hnefati I think it was in a different location. I tried `$ brew install timidity` and then `$ timidity file.midi`, as recommended here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107297/how-can-i-play-a-midi-file-from-terminal/111995. But this didn't work.

Comment: @hnefati  I tried downloading the "GeneralUser" sound font, following the instructions here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107297/how-can-i-play-a-midi-file-from-terminal/111995 , however I did not know how to follow this instruction: "Once you have downloaded and unzipped that, you will have a series of files including "GeneralUser GS FluidSynth v1.44.sf2"...rename that file and moved it to /usr/local/share/fluidsynth/generaluser.v.1.44.sf2."

Comment: @hnefati Trying to download GeneralUser also led to the error I discuss here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348264/euterpea-and-fluidsynth-on-a-mac-yet-more-problems?noredirect=1#comment456546_348264.

Comment: @user65526 Let's keep the conversation [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186294/discussion-between-hnefatl-and-user65526) rather than in the comments.